# How to compare NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType enum values

Tags: swift, enums

I get the following error when trying to compare values received from the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` using this

```
// Check type of transition
if let type = n.userInfo?[NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey] as? UInt {

    FLOG(" transition type is \(type)")

    if (type == NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType.InitialImportCompleted) {
            FLOG(" transition type is NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted")
    }

}
```

But I get the following compiler error

```
NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType is not convertible to UInt
```

Just when I think I have got the hang of Swift i get stumped again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the rare case where the compiler is actually telling you exactly what's wrong! `type` is a `UInt`, while `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType.InitialImportCompleted` is one case of enum. To compare them you need to get them on the same page -- it's probably safest to get the raw value of the enum:

```
if (type == NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType.InitialImportCompleted.toRawValue()) {
    FLOG(" transition type is NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted")
}
```

***Note:*** in Xcode 6.1, enums have changed slightly, so you'd use `.rawValue` instead of `.toRawValue()`.

To handle it the other way, you would need to convert the data from the notification into an enum value. The documentation says: "The corresponding value is one of the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType enum values as an NSNumber object." So the first part of your code is just right, and then you'd need to use the enum's `fromRaw(number)` static method:

```
if let type = n.userInfo?[NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey] as? Uint {
    // convert to enum and unwrap the optional return value
    if let type = NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType.fromRaw(type) {
        // now you can compare directly with the case you want    
        if (type == .InitialImportCompleted) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:*** in Xcode 6.1, you'd use `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType(rawValue: type)` instead of the `fromRaw()` method.

Comment: Thanks, so am I correct in getting the value out of userInfo as a Uint or is there a better way of doing things where its not necessary to get the raw value?

Comment: Updated my answer with more